# How networking works with forwarding disabled?

Tags: networking

I think on most systems the network forwarding is disabled by default - so the computer cannot act as a router.
I wonder, how then does networking inside of the computer work? A few examples:

- hosting a website locally - when we host the site locally and try to access it locally, we have to send an HTTP request - this request needs to be forwarded back to `lo` interface
- virtualization - virtual machines add additional virtual adapters to the computer. It is possible to communicate between various NICs - isn't that also forwarding?

What is then really disabled when network forwarding is disabled in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is incorrect. If the web server listens at 192.168.123.234, the client accesses this address. Traffic is not forwarded to `localhost`.

Second example: Congratulations! You have discovered why the installation of virtualization tools like `libvirt` sets `ip_forward=1`. Yes, forwarding is required here.

Comment: Hmm, so hypervisors actually REQUIRE ip_forwarding for some of the networking setups. Interesting, thanks.